# Find value from List<Dictionary<string, long>>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, dictionary

I've got a list of PaymentPlans and from that I calculated a `List<Dictionary<string, long>>` of price per month.

> string = CampaignCode
>
> long = Price Per Month

I can't get my head around on how to show the price for current PaymentPlan in my view.

```
@Model.PaymentPlans.PricePerMonth.FirstOrDefault(x => x.)
```

This is where my mind is completely blank.

```
public class PaymentPlansIncPPM
{
    public List<PaymentPlan> PaymentPlans { get; set; }
    public List<Dictionary<string, long>> PricePerMonth { get; set; }
}


@foreach (var plan in Model.PaymentPlans)
{
    <div>
        @Html.RadioButton("CampaignId", plan.CampaignCode, new { @id = plan.CampaignCode })
        <label for="@plan.CampaignCode"></label>
        <span>
            <b>@plan.ContractLengthInMonths months</b><br />
            
<-- Here is where I want to show the price per month -->

             $/month
        </span>
    </div>
}
```

edit:
The Dictionary contains one or more, always matching the number of plans. (if it's any help)

```
Key "campaignCode"  string
Value   100000  long

Key "pricePerMonth" string
Value   42  long
```

Comment: @NedStoyanov as i understand - `x` is `Dictionary`, so it has no `Key` property

Comment: Don't use `long` for financial/money values, use `decimal`.

Comment: What is there in the list-of-dictionary? Do you want this? var correctDict = Model.PricePerMonth.First(pm => pm.Kesy.Any(k => k == plan.CampaignCode));
var pricePerMonth = correctDict[plan.CampaignCode];

Comment: @ArghyaC updated with dictionary info

Comment: This works? var correctDict = Model.PricePerMonth.First(dict => dict["campaignCode"] == plan.CampaignCode);
var pricePerMonth = correctDict["pricePerMonth"];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `List<Dictionary<string, long>>` looks like this

```
PricePerMonth (list) :

dict1: [
        {Key: "campaignCode", Value:  100000},
        {Key: "pricePerMonth", Value: 42}
    ]
dict2: [
        {Key: "campaignCode", Value:  100001},
        {Key: "pricePerMonth", Value: 29}
    ]
dict3: [
        {Key: "campaignCode", Value:  100002},
        {Key: "pricePerMonth", Value: 51}
    ]
```

You can get the 'price-per-month' of the campaign (plan.CampaignCode) as

```
var correctDict = Model.PriceMonth.First(dict => dict["campaignCode"] == plan.CampaignCode);
var pricePerMonth = correctDict["pricePerMonth"];
```

Answer (score 2):

You could access the `Dictionary` from the key and loop between the list. For sample:

```
@foreach (var plan in Model.PaymentPlans)
{
    <div>
        @Html.RadioButton("CampaignId", plan.CampaignCode, new { @id = plan.CampaignCode })
        <label for="@plan.CampaignCode"></label>
        <span>
            <strong>@plan.ContractLengthInMonths months</strong><br />
            @{
                var prices = plan.PricePerMonth.FirstOrDefault(d => d.ContainsKey(plan.CampaignCode));

               if (prices != null)
               {
                   foreach(long price in prices[plan.CampaignCode])
                   {
                       <text>
                       <li>@price</li>
                       </text>
                   }    
               }

            }           
             $/month
        </span>
    </div>
}
```

Given you have a list of dictionaries on your Model, you can find the a dictionary where is there a `Key` is equals your `CampaignCode` and show the values of this `Key`. I change the code to show for the first occurrence of the `CampaignCode` but in this structure, you can have a few. Make sure about it.

Comment: i not sure that OP need _all_ values from dictionary and not just for selected `CampaignCode`

Comment: Yea, like @Grundy said. I only need the price for the current plan.

Comment: @Rob, so in list you have only **one** dictionary that contains `CampaignCode` or it can be a few?

Comment: Thank you for comments guys. I've edited my anwser. I did a code like the last one because in a structure  like `List<Dictionary<>>`, you can have a few values. I know you can prepare your code to avoid it, but the structure allows it :)

Comment: @Grundy one or more, always matching the number of plans.